# How can I add multiple emails to notify with this variable (Google Ads Script)?

Tags: google-apps-script

When using this variable in a google ads script to get notified by email, it is only working with one email.

```
var EMAIL_ADDRESS_TO_NOTIFY = "x@gmail.com";
```

How do I do so that multiple emails could get notified? I would like to add more than one email.

Here is my script, so it looks like the first row with the email would need to be changed:

```
var EMAIL_ADDRESS_TO_NOTIFY = "x@company.com"; 
var NUM_HOURS_TO_CHECK = 6;
var METRIC_TO_CHECK = "Impressions";
var DEBUG = 0;
Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function() {
   var yyyy = this.getFullYear().toString();
   var mm = (this.getMonth()+1).toString();
   var dd = this.getDate().toString();
   ....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function emailNotification(email) {
  const emails = ["email1","email2","email..."];
  let idx = emails.indexOf(email);
  if(~idx) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for following up :-)
here is my script so it looks like the first row with the email would need to be changed:

var EMAIL_ADDRESS_TO_NOTIFY = "x@company.com";
var NUM_HOURS_TO_CHECK = 6;
var METRIC_TO_CHECK = "Impressions";

var DEBUG = 0;

Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function() {
    var yyyy = this.getFullYear().toString();
    var mm = (this.getMonth()+1).toString(); 
    var dd  = this.getDate().toString();
   
    
....

thanks,